# How to convert timestamp into days ago

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

I have my MySQL database inserting timestamp when I upload a record, so what's entered is something like 2013-02-02 16:59:29. Is there a Java way to convert that into something like 10 Days Ago?

Comment: Um okay, they are just tag lines. Chill.

Comment: They're how this site is organized. You've been around long enough to know better.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you've read the datetime value from the database into java:

```
Date date; // read from database
int days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(
     System.currentTimeMillis() - date.getTime());
```

then you can format it as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch time from mysql with the help of resultset and pass time data to below method

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {                

     long timStampFromMysql = rs.getTimestamp("time");// Fetch time from mysql
                Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTimeInMillis(convertTime(timStampFromMysql , 15));
                System.out.println(cal);

            }

            public static long convertTime(long timeInMillies, int days)
            {

                 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillies);
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);

                    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();



            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Days.daysBetween` from the [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library will compute that for you.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(time_ms);
DateTime end   = new DateTime(now);
Days days = Days.daysBetween(start, end);
int d = days.getDays();
```